# Subscript list(?)

Tags: matrices, subscripts

How to make matrix like in picture in LaTeX (kind of stacked subscripts):

[image: Photo]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for bmatrix env. and \substack macro

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\ 
  3 & 4 \\ 
  8 & 10
\end{bmatrix}_{%
  \substack{\mathrm{I}+\mathrm{II}  \hfill \\ 
            \mathrm{III}-\mathrm{I} \hfill \\ 
            \mathrm{III}-\mathrm{II}
  }
}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you prefer the elements of the `\substack` directive to be centered horizontally instead of left-aligned, just omit the two `\hfill` directives.

---

*Addendum*, prompted by @egreg's comment: Instead of `\substack{...}`, one could also use `\begin{subarray}{l} ... \end{subarray}`:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\ 
  3 & 4 \\ 
  8 & 10
\end{bmatrix}_{%
  \begin{subarray}{l}
    \mathrm{I}+\mathrm{II}  \\ 
    \mathrm{III}-\mathrm{I} \\ 
    \mathrm{III}-\mathrm{II}
  \end{subarray}
}
\]
```

For more information about the `\substack` macro and the `subarray` environment, please see section 7.1, "Multiline subscripts and superscripts", of the user guide of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Or `\begin{subarray}{l} first \\ second \\ third \end{subarray}`

Comment: @egreg - thanks! I've edited my answer to incorporate your suggestion.